# How is $k \otimes_k (M \otimes_A k) \cong (M \otimes_A k)$ as $A$-modules, where $M$ is a $k$-module and $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> How is $k \otimes_k (M \otimes_A k) \cong (M \otimes_A k)$ as $A$-modules, where $M$ is a $k$-module and $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$?

I am getting confused with something I'm sure is very basic and I would appreciate clarification.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal, and let $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$.
Let $M$ be an $A$-module and write $M_k = (k \otimes_A M)$. Then I know that $M_k \otimes_k k \cong M_k$ as $k$-modules, because $M_k$ is a $k$-module. but how can I show that $M_k \otimes_k k \cong M_k$ as $A$-modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object $M_k \otimes_k k$ does not changr when you consider it as a $k$- or an $A$-module.

The statement you say you “know” can be worded more precisely as: “the canonical map $f: M_k \otimes_k k \rightarrow M_k$ is an isomorphism of $k$-modules”. But it’s a valid statement to ask whether this map (which, again, is a well-defined set-theoretical application and by the above a bijection) is an isomorphism of $A$-modules.

Because it’s already a bijection, it’s enough to check that it is $A$-linear. But if $a\in A$ has reduction $\alpha \in k$, $a$ acts (on both sides) as $\alpha$ and the map does preserve $\alpha$. In mathematical language, for every $x$ in the source, $f(a \cdot x)=f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)=a \cdot f(x)$, so $f$ is indeed $A$-linear.

Answer (score 3):

That is because we have a chain of canonical isomorphisms:
$$k\otimes_k(M\otimes_Ak)\simeq (M\otimes_Ak)\otimes_k k\simeq M\otimes_A(k\otimes_k k)\simeq M\otimes_Ak$$

Comment: Is it not even more simple than that? That $k\otimes_k R\simeq R$ for all $k$-modules $R$?

Comment: You're quite right – I had a small doubt because, it mixes the $k$-vector space and $A$-module structures, but it works by restriction of scalars.

Comment: Yeah that's fair, I actually had that same doubt just after I posted this comment.

Comment: over which modules are these isomorphisms defined?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean exactly – is it ‘for modules over which rings are they defined’?